# How to fix the binding of the "location" property of member elements within a group in the palette?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I've been tweaking the Floor Planner project from GoJS and I want to make my own customized item (grouped elements) in the palette area. I was able to generate an item but the elements within the group are not reacting to the node template map I've set-up as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

What I was expecting is to have a grouped element like this:

[image]

This is how I set-up my template maps:

**For the blue lines**

```
function makeBlueLine() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    return $(go.Node, "Auto",
    {
        contextMenu: makeContextMenu(),
        selectionObjectName: "SHAPE",
        selectionAdorned: false,
        resizeAdornmentTemplate: makeWallPartResizeAdornment(),
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Left,
        toolTip: makeNodeToolTip(),
        resizable: true,
        resizeObjectName: "SHAPE",
        rotatable: true,
        doubleClick: function (e) { if (e.diagram.floorplanUI) e.diagram.floorplanUI.hideShow("selectionInfoWindow"); },
    },
    new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
    new go.Binding("visible", "showOnPlan"),
    new go.Binding("angle", "angle"),
    $(go.Shape,
    { name: "SHAPE", fill: "blue", stroke: "#000", strokeWidth: 1, height: 1, figure: "Rectangle" },
    new go.Binding("width", "length").makeTwoWay(),
    new go.Binding("stroke", "isSelected", function (s, obj) {
                return s ? "green" : "blue";
            }).ofObject(),
    ),
  );
}
```

**For the Group**

```
function makeLineContainer() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    return $(go.Group, "Vertical",
        {
            //isSubGraphExpanded: false,
            contextMenu: makeContextMenu(),
            doubleClick: function (e) {
                if (e.diagram.floorplanUI) e.diagram.floorplanUI.hideShow("selectionInfoWindow");
            },
            toolTip: makeGroupToolTip()
        },
        new go.Binding("location", "loc"),
          $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", { fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", stroke: null, name: 'SHAPE', strokeCap: 'square' },
              new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", function (s, obj) {
                  return s ? "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.10)" : "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
              }).ofObject()
              ),
            $(go.Placeholder, { padding: 5 })
          )
        )
}
```

This is my model array set-up:

```
BLUE_LINE_DATA_ARRAY = [
    {
        category: "LineParent",
        key: "Type1",
        isGroup: true,
    },
    {
        category: "BlueLine",
        group: "Type1",
        loc: '0 0',
        angle: 90,
        length: 50,
        key: "G1",
    },
    {
        category: "BlueLine",
        group: "Type1",
        loc: '10 10',
        angle: 0,
        length: 50,
        key: "G2",
    },  
];
```

For the palette initialization, I haven't done any change except adding the group template map there. Here's the template mapping I've made:

```
this.nodeTemplateMap.add("BlueLine", makeBlueLine());
this.groupTemplateMap.add("LineParent", makeLineContainer());
```

I couldn't find what I'm missing. I've also checked on the macros.html sample and everything looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried implementing such a sample, but I was unable to encounter any problems with groups in a Palette.  Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2019 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
  <script src="go.js"></script>

  <script>
    function init() {
      var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

      // initialize main Diagram
      myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          { "undoManager.isEnabled": true });

      myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Auto",
          new go.Binding("location", "location", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
          $(go.Shape,
            { fill: "white", stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 2 },
            new go.Binding("stroke", "color")),
          $(go.TextBlock,
            { margin: 4 },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

      // initialize Palette
      myPalette =
        $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",
          { nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap });

      myPalette.model.nodeDataArray = [
        { key: 1, group: 3, text: "blue node", color: "blue", location: "30 0" },
        { key: 2, group: 3, text: "orange node", color: "orange", location: "0 40" },
        { key: 3, isGroup: true, text: "GROUP" }
      ];

      // initialize Overview
      myOverview =
        $(go.Overview, "myOverviewDiv",
          { observed: myDiagram, contentAlignment: go.Spot.Center });

      load();
    }

    // save a model to and load a model from Json text, displayed below the Diagram
    function save() {
      var str = myDiagram.model.toJson();
      document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = str;
    }
    function load() {
      var str = document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value;
      myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(str);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0 2px 0 0">
      <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="flex-grow: 1; width: 120px; background-color: whitesmoke; border: solid 1px black"></div>
      <div id="myOverviewDiv" style="margin: 2px 0 0 0; width: 120px; height: 100px; background-color: lightgray; border: solid 1px black"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="flex-grow: 1; height: 400px; border: solid 1px black"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="loadModel" onclick="load()">Load</button>
    <button id="saveModel" onclick="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
  <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:200px">
{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [
{"key":1, "text":"hello", "color":"green", "location":"0 0"},
{"key":2, "text":"world", "color":"red", "location":"70 0"}
  ],
  "linkDataArray": [
{"from":1, "to":2}
  ]}
  </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how the group appears in the Palette, and when a copy is dropped in the main Diagram.  Each of the two member nodes are located according to the binding, and they remain in that relative location, until the user moves a member node in the main diagram.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Walter. Yeah, I also tried changing the Macros.html sample that came with the goJS downloadable and it works fine as intended. It's just with the floor planner sample that it's acting in a different way. I've tried stripping down the listeners and custom method calls but still no luck. Could it have been with how the palette is declared within floor planner? It's the only thing I can find that was implemented differently with the sample you gave and with the Macros.html sample.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to look into this some more but unfortunately, I still haven't found a definitive reason or cause of the issue. However, I did find a workaround but it will costed me the ability to have multiple palettes for the floor planner. So basically, I changed the palette constructor of the floor planner package to follow the pattern of the samples for palette found in GoJS website.

How it was declared first:

```
function FloorplanPalette(div, floorplan, nodeDataArray) {
    go.Palette.call(this, div);

    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    this.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel, { nodeDataArray: nodeDataArray });
    this.contentAlignment = go.Spot.Center;
    this.nodeTemplateMap = floorplan.nodeTemplateMap;
    this.groupTemplateMap = floorplan.groupTemplateMap;
    this.toolManager.contextMenuTool.isEnabled = false;

    // add this new FloorplanPalette to the "palettes" field of its associated Floorplan
    floorplan.palettes.push(this);
} go.Diagram.inherit(FloorplanPalette, go.Palette);
```

My change:

```
function FloorplanPalette(div, floorplan, nodeDataArray) {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    myPalette =
    $(go.Palette, div,  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
        nodeTemplateMap: floorplan.nodeTemplateMap,
        groupTemplateMap: floorplan.groupTemplateMap,
        contentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        });

    myPalette.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray);
}
```